# .htaccess URL rewrite to point to ajax file

Tags: .htaccess

I'm struggling to add a rewrite rule to my .htaccess file.

I need the URL stings in this format:

/myFile.ajax

to point to this:

```
/include/dir/ajax.myFile.php
```

Here's where I am:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+include/dir/ajax\.([^.]+)\.php[/\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1\.ajax? [R=302,L]
```

Not sure what I'm missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try also adding:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)\.ajax$ /include/dir/ajax.$1.php [L]
```